# Appengine Java on IntelliJ: getResourceAsStream null on debug mode (google cloud endpoints v2)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, intellij-idea, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

**Story:**
I was using google cloud endpoints 1.0 with android studio without any problem. However google decided to move cloud tools plugin from Android Studio to IntelliJ idea so I migrated my project to cloud endpoints 2.0 by following https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/migrating

**Problem:**
I followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/deploy-local) for local deploy and debug. I can debug my code by running AppengineDebug [image: appengine-debug-options] but

```
InputStream stream =  MyApi.class.getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("sample.json");
```

**returns null.**

sample.json file is located at `src/main/resources`

**appengine-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<runtime>java8</runtime>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

<system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
</system-properties>
<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
<resource-files>
    <include path="/**.json"/>
</resource-files>
```

When I run **appengineRun** task from gradle getResourceAsStream works successfully but I'm unable debug code by running appengineRun task

**Question**
1- How can I debug code by running appengineRun task?

2- How can I read resources folder when I run AppengineDebug

Comment: for question 1) you can can follow the [guide here](https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/deploy-local#community) for Community Edition to use the gradle plugin appengineRun task and then attach a remote debugger in IntelliJ to debug locally. for 2) is this a multi-module project? Under "artifacts to deploy" in your run config how many modules show up? I'm asking because I'm wondering if you are targeting the correct module.

Comment: Another update: I tested this out myself using the built in local dev run configuration (i.e. your "Appengine Debug" run config) and it works (the stream was properly loaded). If you could update the question with some more details about your project setup I can help debug further.